# How to slow down slide speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am using the intro slider found here http://www.jssor.com/demos/introduction-slider.html but I cannot figure out how to slow the slider down. I can slow the captions down, but not the slider.

I have tried messing with the delay and duration but I cannot seem to get it working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Slider HTML
        
        
            /* this line can be removed, but it really helps in case of css conflicts in your page */
            .slider1 div { position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

```
    <!-- Loading Screen --> 
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;

            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%; height:100%;"> 
        </div> 
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;

            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <!-- Slides Container --> 
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 980px; height: 380px;
        overflow: hidden;">

           <!--START SLIDE 1-->           
        <div> 
        <img u="image" src="img/home/01.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="CLIP|LR" t2="B" du="1500" class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:420px; top: 20px; width:470px; height:40px;font-size:30px"> 
            18" Drop Deck Beaver Tail Model 
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="FADE" t2="B" d=-50  class=captionBlack style="position: absolute; left:20px;top:275px;width:400px;height:60px;">
            The Logging Industry's Most Vesatile Trailer Allows You to Haul Equipment to the Wood, Logs to the Mill and Lumber to Market!
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End SLIDE 1--> 

        <!--START SLIDE 2-->
        <div>
        <img u="image" src="img/home/02.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="RTTS|T" d=-100 t2="B" class=captionRed style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 20px; width:300px; height:20px; font-size:30px"> 
            12" Drop Deck Model
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="T|IB" t2="T" d=-100 class="captionRed"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 280px; width:430px; height:60px;"> 
            Offers a Lower Center of Gravity for Improved Ride &amp; Increased Height Capacity. Hauls Both Logs and All Types of Lumber Products with Ease.
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End SLIDE 2-->


        <!--START SLIDE 3-->
        <div> 
            <img u="image" src="img/home/03.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="L" d=-750 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 20px; width:250px; height:70px; font-size:28px; line-height:30px; text-align:center"> 
            Straight Frame Log &amp; Lumber Trailer
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="R|IB" t2=R d=-900 class="captionBlack" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:250px;width:460px;height:75px;">Offering the same great list of Standard Features at a lower price point, while still offereing the flexibility to haul logs and lumber products. (shown with optional mid-mounted knuckleboom)</div>
        </div>
        <!--End SLIDE 3-->

        <!--START SLIDE 4-->
        <div>
        <img u="image" src="img/home/04.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="CLIP|LR" du="2500" class="captionRed"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:400px; height:100px;"> 
            Built with the same square tubing design that delivers maximum strength while allowing you to haul both logs and lumber on the same trailer. Available in Straight Tongue and Self-Steer Designs to fit Your Application.
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="L|IB" t2=L d=-900 class="captionRed"  style="position:absolute; left:600px; top: 30px; width:330px; height:20px; font-size:30px"> 
            Pup Trailers &amp; Log Beds
            </div> 
        </div>
        <!--End SLIDE 4-->



        </div>
```

Slider JS

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Collapse Random
        {$Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, $Delay: 50, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }
        //Fade in LR Chess
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, y: 0.3, $Cols: 2, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true }
        //Rotate VDouble+ out
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 150, x: -1, y: 2, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.85} }
        //Swing Inside in Stairs
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }
        //Zoom HDouble+ out
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 4, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 11, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
        //Dodge Pet Inside in Stairs
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        //Rotate Zoom+ out BL
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 4, y: -4, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} }
        //Dodge Dance Inside in Random
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.3, y: -0.3, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        //Rotate VFork+ out
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: -3, y: 1, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 28 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} }
        //Clip and Chess in
        , { $Duration: 1050, y: -1, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Top: [0.5, 0.5], $Clip: [0, 0.5] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $ScaleClip: 0.5 }
        //Swing Inside in Swirl
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationSwirl, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }
        //Rotate Zoom+ out
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} }
        //Dodge Pet Inside in ZigZag
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        //Rotate Zoom- out TL
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} }
        //Rotate Zoom- in BR
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Top: [0.2, 0.8], $Zoom: [0.2, 0.8], $Rotate: [0.2, 0.8] }, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} }
        // Wave out Eagle
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, y: -0.5, $Delay: 60, $Cols: 24, $SlideOut: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationCircle, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Round: { $Top: 1.5} }
        //Expand Stairs
        , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2050, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }
        //Fade Clip out H
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 3, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
        //Dodge Pet Inside in Random Chess
        , { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Top: [0.2, 0.8] }, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15, $Row: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        ];

        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html#captiondefinition
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html

        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["TR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["L|IB"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R|IB"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T|IB"] = { $Duration: 1500, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 1500, $Clip: 3, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|TB"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 12, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|T"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 4, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["WV|B"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.2, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Left: 1.5} };

        _CaptionTransitions["TORTUOUS|VB"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["LISTH|R"] = { $Duration: 250, $Delay: 50, x: -0.8, $Clip: 1, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic, $ScaleClip: 0.8, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.4, 0.6], $Clip: [0, 0.4], $Opacity: [0.4, 0.6]} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|360"] = { $Duration: 900, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["T|IE*IE"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.8, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1.5, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutElastic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInElastic, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutElastic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Zoom: [0, 0.8], $Opacity: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTTS|R"] = { $Duration: 2900, x: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTTS|T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} };

        _CaptionTransitions["DDGDANCE|RB"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.3, y: -0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["DDG|TR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.3, y: 0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["FLTTR|R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.2, y: -0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };
        _CaptionTransitions["FLTTRWN|LT"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.5, y: 0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.7], $Top: [0.1, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["ATTACK|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.1, y: -0.5, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["FADE"] = { $Duration: 500, $Opacity: 2 };

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
            $SlideDuration: 35000,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 4,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$SetScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 980), 300));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }


        //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
        //    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //}
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set $SlideDuration option. Also you can try to set `$Idle` option.

Reference: [Adjust Slider Speed - Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-adjust-speed.html)

Comment: That is already in there. No matter what I change the number to, it still doesnt change.

Comment: There are 4 kinds of speed you can set. Caption animation, slideshow animation, sliding left <-> right and period to stay in current slide. Please let me know which one need to change.